# How do I remove all elements of a given class

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to convert this to CoffeeScript, but coming up short:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByClassName('hi');

while(paras[0]) {
    paras[0].parentNode.removeChild(paras[0]);
}​
```

How do I do this in CoffeeScript?

Comment: This should be a fairly straightforward conversion, what have you tried and what errors did you come across?

Answer (score 0):

Per @caffeinated.tech's comment, it'd be beneficial for people answering the question and for people visiting this question in the future to see what you've tried.

That all being said, you could use use CoffeeScript's list-like comprehensions to do something like this:

```
his = document.getElementsByClassName('hi')
hi.remove hi for hi in his
```